problem with web app using docker with nginx
This web application is supposed to display information such as: IP address of the server on which the application is running,
Server name (hostname) and Application version (in any scheme) - the application version is to be specified in the docker  --build-arg by giving value
the VERSION variable defined by the ARG statements. I using simple index.js. The result of the application is that the js code itself appears on the website.
I used commands like:
docker build --build-arg VERSION=2 -f Dockerfile1 -t local/base:v1 .
docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name web1 local/base:v1
curl http://localhost:8080

and it shows that container is healthy
FROM node AS build1

# Set the working directory in the image
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Copy application files
COPY . .

# Install npm dependencies
RUN npm install

# Set the environment variable for application version
ARG VERSION
ENV APP_VER=production.${VERSION:-v1.0}

# Stage 2: Utilize the Nginx base image
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy the Nginx configuration file handling JavaScript files
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy the built application from the first stage to the Nginx image
COPY --from=build1 /usr/app /usr/share/nginx/html

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Set the port on which the HTTP server will run
EXPOSE 80

# Set the default page
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

# Health check: check if the server is available at localhost:80
HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=5s \
  CMD curl --silent --fail localhost:80 || exit 1

const os = require('os');

const app = express();
const port = 8080;

// Define the main path ("/")
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // Construct the response with server IP address, hostname, and application version
    let response = `Server IP Address: ${getIPAddress()}\n`;
    response += `Server Name (hostname): ${os.hostname()}\n`;
    response += `Application Version: ${process.env.VERSION}\n`;
    // Send the response as HTML
    res.send(response);
});

// Serve HTML file
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Listen on port and log a message upon server start
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`The application is available on port ${port}`);
});

// Function to get the server IP address
function getIPAddress() {
    // Get network interfaces
    const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
    for (const dev in interfaces) {
        // Filter IPv4 addresses, excluding internal addresses
        const iface = interfaces[dev].filter(details => details.family === 'IPv4' && !details.internal);
        // Return the first found address
        if (iface.length > 0) return iface[0].address;
    }
    // Return default value
    return '0.0.0.0';
}

    # Listen on this port as default
    listen 80 default_server;
    # Listen for ipv6
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # Serve static files
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.js;

    location / {
        # If request does not match any file
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}


The second half of your Dockerfile sets up an Nginx server, which normally only can serve static files (for example, a prebuilt pure-React application).  It doesn't contain a Node interpreter at all.  Does it work to delete the Nginx build stage and set your image's CMD to run your server?
